# image doesn't scale well when I rotate my phone even though max-height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, media-queries, samsung-mobile

So in another post I was suggested to use `max-height:100%` but it doesn't help and when I rotate my Galaxy S4 and it enters the landscape mode, the height doesn't scale well and I just see part of the image despite the whole height. Any other solution to this?

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
<p align="center"><img src="https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_00pfOKSXTudGqfb" style="height: 470px;" /></p>
<style type="text/css">/* iphone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}
/* samsung */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 321px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}

}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
img {max-width: 100%;  }
}
</style>
```

This is what I see when I rotate my phone horizontally (landscape mode)
[image]

I used the following jQuery but when I flip the phone it's like 90(or80)% of the image is just shown. Any idea how to fix this?
Here 's the jQuery code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dVKz/5/
and here's what I see:
[image]

Comment: What is it that you would like to happen?  You can definitely use media queries that will target modern devices like your S4.  For example, you can target the orientation of the device like this: @media screen and (max-device-width: 1000px) and (orientation:landscape) {...}.  But what do you want to have happen? Should the image scale and retain it's proportions? Should it fit the screen edge-to-edge regardless of the aspect ratio? Should no part of it get cut off?

Comment: I want the whole height of the image be shown when I am in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using JS (jQuery in particular) is to listen to window resize `$(window).resize()` and then adjust the image's size to fit the screen.

I used this method when building a web gallery for mobile devices. I couldn't find a better way to do that with just CSS...

Edit:
Calculate the image's height and width:

```
var $img = $('your image selector here');
$img.css({
    maxWidth : $(window).width(),
    maxHeight : $(window).height()
});
// This is set in a different command because of the dependencies with the properties above.
// Do not merge these together.
$img.css({
    marginLeft : $img.width() / (-2),
    top: ($(window).height() - $img.height()) / 2
})
```

Comment: so it is not fixable using CSS media queries?

Comment: I actually had this but didn't know how to center the image: http://jsfiddle.net/7dVKz/3/

Comment: Well, CSS isn't that flexible... As far as my experience show me.
If you want to center the image, and you're already using jQuery, you could simply calculate the position of the image according to its size.